# Reduce number of tooltips in a column graph?

Tags: mschart

I have a column graph that hold 500 000 values. When I addning tooltip the application run extra slow.

My question is: How can I only add tooltip to columns that has values over a certain level?

Answer (score 0):

Generate the HTML code using PHP, check for every column that you generate - the level and if it's above the threshold you set - create a tooltip.